# What's the benefit of multiline code with multple variables compared to combined actions pygame.mouse.getpos() that combine them

Tags: python, pygame, formatting, mouseevent

I'm pretty new to python and just started learning to build my first game. A tutorial I was watching got an image to move along with the mouse pointer. I had already worked out my own version of it before following his tutorial, and I guess I am just wondering if the difference in the two codes are simply down to personal choice or if there is a particular benefits of using his format over what I did. I realise for this specific action it is probably irrelevant in the grand scheme of things, but I am just thinking more about in general as I build my own coding practices and style.

I kinda see pro's and con's to both in that his might be easier to test if things need debugging as the variables can be adjusted and it's maybe seen as more readable. But in very large software I assume efficiency and saving on characters would possibly counts.

His...

```
       if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION and event.buttons[0] == 1:
            mouse_x = event.pos[0]
            mouse_y = event.pos[1]
            zombie_DBS_rect.centerx = mouse_x
            zombie_DBS_rect.centery = mouse_y
```

mine...

```
       if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION and event.buttons[0] == 1:
            zombie_DBS_rect.center = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
```

Comment: The first might be easier to debug as you can place a breakpoint on any of those lines however it is likely slower (just a hunch). It might come down to the speed of `event.pos` vs `pygame.mouse.get_pos()`. I would probably try `zombie_DBS_rect.center = event.pos` if speed was an issue. Other than that the first is slightly easier to debug in my opinion.

Comment: mouse_x and mouse_y are completely unnecessary in this code. Maybe they are being used later in the code, but as stands, they would be flagged in any decent code review. In the other case with a centerx, centery verses center, its a question of how others use this variable, so not much we can say,

Comment: `pygame.mouse.get_pos()` is the current mouse position but `event.pos` is the position of the mouse at time of the event. Why not `zombie_DBS_rect.center = event.pos`?